# how to implement timers in multithread environment in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I normally use single thread process with signal handlers and to achieve concurrency, by dividing parallel tasks into multiple process.

Now, i am trying to check if multi-threading can be faster. To implement alarms/timers, i typically register alarmHandlers and let OS send a signal. But in multi-threading environment, i cannot take this approach, UNLESS, there is a way such that signal can be delivered to a specific thread.

Hence my question, how to implement timers in multithreading environment? I can start a thread and let it sleep for desired amount and then set a shared variable. What other options do i have?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to start threads at different times.
You can use the sleep_until function.
This is a C++11 function
The thread will sleep until a certain moment
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until

So if you have several tasks to do your code would look like that:

```
int PerformTask(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock,Duration>& sleep_time, TaskParameters)
{
     sleep_until(sleep_time);
     PerformTask(TaskParameters);
}
```

Hope that helps,

Comment: Jeremy Friesner's account is a good response for the pre-C++11 world, and let that be all the more reason to appreciate how C++11 (1) standardizes multithreading so it doesn't depend on OS/API/etc and (2) can keep your code readable. +1

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which environment (OS, API, etc) you are using so any answers you get are going to have to be fairly general.

From your example about starting a thread and having it sleep for a while and then set a shared variable, it sounds like what you're trying to do is have multiple threads all do something special at a particular time, correct?

If so, one easy way to do it would be to choose the alarm-time before spawning the threads, so that each thread can know in advance when to do the special action.  Then its just a matter of coding each thread to "watch the clock" and do the action at the appointed time.

But let's say that you don't know in advance when the alarm is supposed to go off.  In that case, what I think you need is a mechanism of inter-thread communication.  Once you have a way for one thread to send a signal/message to another thread, you can use that to tell the target thread(s) when it's time for them to do the alarm-action.

There are various APIs to do that, but the way I like to use (because it's cross-platform portable and uses the standard BSD sockets API) is to create an entirely-local socket connection before spawning each thread.  Under Unix/Posix, you can do this quite easily by calling socketpair().  Under Windows there isn't a socketpair() function to call but you can roll your own socketpair() via the usual networking calls (socket(),bind(),listen(),accept() for one socket, then socket() and connect() to create the other socket and connect it to the first end).

Once you have the pair of connected sockets, you have your parent thread keep only the first socket, and the newly-spawned thread keeps only the second socket.  Et voila, now your parent thread and child thread can communicate with each other over the socket.  E.g. if your parent thread wants the child thread to do something, it can send() a byte on its socket and the child thread will recv() that byte on its socket, or vice versa if the child thread wants to tell the parent to do something.

In that way, the parent thread could spawn a bunch of threads and then send a byte on each thread's socket when the alarm time arrived.  The child threads in the meantime could be doing work and polling their socket via non-blocking recv() calls, or if they prefer to sleep while waiting for the alarm, they could block inside select() or recv() or whatever.

Note that you don't have to send all of your cross-thread data over the socketpair if you don't want to; usually I just lock a mutex, add a command object to a FIFO queue, unlock the mutex, and then send a single byte.  When the child thread receives that byte, it responds by locking the same mutex, popping the command object off of the FIFO queue, unlocking the mutex, and then executing the command.  That way you can used shared memory to "send" arbitrarily large amounts of data to the child thread without having to send lots of bytes across the socket.  The one byte that is sent acts as only a "signal" to wake up the child thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Implement a timer with boost::asio**

Here is a timer class witch we used in our project, witch project deal with 4Gbit/s internet flow(about 3.0-4.0 million timers). The timer is suit for most generaly work.

timer.h

```
/*
 * Timer
 * Licensed under Apache
 *
 * Author: KaiWen <wenkai1987@gmail.com>
 * Date: Apr-16-2013
 *
 */
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

typedef boost::asio::deadline_timer* timer_ptr;

namespace bs = boost::system;

class timer;
class timer_node;

class tm_callback {
public:
    explicit tm_callback(boost::function<void(timer_node&)>& f) : m_f(f)
    {
    }

    void operator()(timer_node& node, const bs::error_code& e) {
        if (!e)
            m_f(node);
    }
private:
    boost::function<void(timer_node&)> m_f;
};

class timer_node {
    friend class timer;
public:
    timer_node() {}
    timer_node(timer_ptr p, int ms, boost::function<void(timer_node&)> f) :
        m_tptr(p), m_ms(ms), m_callback(f)
    {
    }

    void reset(unsigned int ms = 0, boost::function<void(timer_node&)> f = 0) {
        if (ms)
            m_tptr->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(ms));
        else
            m_tptr->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(m_ms));

        if (f)
            m_tptr->async_wait(boost::bind<void>(tm_callback(f), *this, _1));
        else
            m_tptr->async_wait(boost::bind<void>(tm_callback(m_callback), *this, _1));
    }
private:
    timer_ptr m_tptr;
    int m_ms;
    boost::function<void(timer_node&)> m_callback;
};
```

timer.cpp

```
/*
 * Timer
 *
 * Licensed under Apache
 *
 * Author: KaiWen <wenkai1987@gmail.com>
 * Date: Apr-16-2013
 *
 */
#include "timer.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/ptime.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::asio;

timer::timer(int thread_num) : m_next_ios(0), m_size(0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
        io_service_ptr p(new ba::io_service);
        work_ptr pw(new ba::io_service::work(*p));
        m_ios_list.push_back(p);
        m_works.push_back(pw);
    }

    pthread_spin_init(&m_lock, 0);
}

timer::~timer() {
    pthread_spin_destroy(&m_lock);
}

void timer::run() {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_ios_list.size(); i++)
        m_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&ba::io_service::run, &*m_ios_list[i]))->detach();
}
```

If you like, combine the timer.cpp to the timer.h, then there is just a header file. A simple usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "timer.h"

timer t(3);

void callback(timer_node& nd) {
    std::cout << "time out" << std::endl;
    t.del_timer(nd);
}

int main(void) {
    t.run();

    t.add_timer(5000, callback);    // set timeout 5 seconds

    sleep(6);

    return 0;
}
```

**Implement a thread special timer**

There is a lock in the timer above, witch cause the program not very *fast*.  You can implement your owen thread special timer, witch not use lock, and not block, fater than the timer above , but this need a 'driver' and implement hardly. Here is a way we implement  it:

```
pkt = get_pkt();
if (pkt) {
    now = pkt->sec;
    timer.execut_timer(now);
}
```

Now, here is no lock, and non-block and boost your performance, we use it to deal with 10GBit/s internet flow(about 8.0-9.0 million timers). But this is implement dependence. Hope help you.